# Getting data from API: Problem with Array and map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I’m a beginner and got problem with nested array.

This is API where I want to get some info from, I have been doing it many sometimes, but usually it was just one array or single info. I have tried to resolve it for many ways but I don’t know how to change my code to get proper back:
name, title, description, urlToImage.

I guess there is problem with const [news, setNews] = useState([]); and maybe useEffect(() => {
getNews();
}, []);

I don’t know what to put there with more nested array instead of „[]”.

Below its my code (including API).

NewsApp.jsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import NewsCard from "./NewsCard.jsx";


function NewsApp() {

    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, []);


    const getNews = async () => {
        
    const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=7f6de317d6ff4d3582ee52c9559f2c36');
    const data = await response.json();
    setNews(data)
    console.log(data)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {news.map(item =>
            <NewsCard 
            name={item.articles[0].source.name}
            title={item.articles[0].title}
            description={item.articles[0].description}
            urlToImage={item.articles[0].urlToImage} />)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewsApp;
```

and NewsCard.jsx below:

```
import React from 'react';

function NewsCard(props) {
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>{props.item.name}</h2>
                <h4>{props.item.title}</h4>
                <p>{props.description}</p>
                <a href={props.urlToImage}></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewsCard;
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me, this app is missing to finish my whole project.

Comment: can you share your response from `getNews`. apart from that, you can also use `NewsCard({name, title, description, urlToImage})`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API you are using returns on object, not an array. I haven't tested, but I would try the following

```
import NewsCard from "./NewsCard.jsx";

function NewsApp() {

    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNews();
    }, []);


    const getNews = async () => {
        
    const response = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=7f6de317d6ff4d3582ee52c9559f2c36');
    const data = await response.json();
    setNews(data.articles)
    console.log(data)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {news.map(article =>
            <NewsCard 
            name={article.source.name}
            title={article.title}
            description={article.description}
            urlToImage={article.urlToImage} />)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewsApp;
```

Notice that when you call setNews(), you use the data.articles, which is an array. Instead of map to iterate the articles, I use forEach. Let me know how this works out.

EDIT: Looks like you use .map, not .forEach in React.

Comment: I think it is rightly pointed out by @matthewjselby it is an { }, and it contains articles as a property.

Comment: Thanks, It's working now, but I used map instead of forEach and it's perfect.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please mark as the answer when you get a chance.